# opening application from the sms/email link

Tags: android

Let us suppose if I send any message (recommendation) from my mobile to a friends phone who  clicks on the link to install application(which is run on my friend's device).

I couldn't get the right ideas to do that.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a [custom scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023273/android-custom-url-scheme) (i.e. a special type of 'link'). If you send such a link via SMS and user clicks on it, then a registered app will be started.

**Edited to provide example:**

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="com.yourhostname"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Where you change `com.yourhostname` for your site hostname. So of you send some url in SMS that contains this hostname, e.g. 'http://www.yourhostname.com/some-generated-path', then if user has you app installed this link will be opened by the app, but if not then link will be opened in browser still giving you opportunity to show the content to this user.

Comment: sorry can you give me the suitable example from your end.

Comment: @Peter: By doing it this way, it still shows the option of Browser right? Is there a way in which in only opens my app directly without giving the option of browsers?

Comment: Has anyone successfully used a custom URI Scheme link from SMS instead of http(s)? I cannot get the custom links to show as clickable. http(s) work fine.