# How to Start Application from link in sms in android?

Tags: android

I want to Start Application installed in phone by giving link through SMS.
Anyone Have Idea?

Is it working on emulator?

Comment: Try this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954007/opening-application-from-the-sms-email-link

Comment: And welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of resources to do this. The Twitter API also uses a callback link which launches an app because the app is registered to launch that intent or at least offer the user to use that application when the link is clicked or followed.

[Make a link in the Android browser start up my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app)

[Launch custom android application from android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)

[Android Docs - Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)