# Android Development: How can my App launch other app and do a task?

Tags: android

It seems easy to start other apps in my program. But can I do some specific after launching other apps?

For example, we can launch a browser, and let it visit a specific website. We can also launch google maps to search for some address.

But for other apps, can I do this? Such as start a music app and let it play songs, or launch a photo processing app, load a specific image, and run some functions on it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not all apps supply this function. if supplied, for example a Music app, your can add the music file path via Intent extra data, more detail you must analy the specific app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use intents to switch between apps.  These employ a Url Schema registered by the app.  Your inquery about opening a browser would just require a web url. The url starting with `http://` will launch the browser. The browser, when starting, will also look for data assigned to the intent instance that might be passed.

Look at [Sending an Intent to browser to open specific URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/android-sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url) for a code example.

Your control as to what can been done after you launch an external app will be limited to the implementation the app provides.  If you own the app you can handle external intents. You can view more information on setting up custom Url schemes registration and handling here:

[android custom url scheme..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023273/android-custom-url-scheme)