# Custom URL Scheme Handler in Android

Tags: android, url, protocols, url-scheme

Hi I'm looking for a way for my application to respond to a specific URL scheme such as myapp:// for example. I know you can register a url scheme to launch applications and such but that is not what I am looking for.

I want my app to call a method and return a certain string when it sees the custom url scheme essentially intercepting the request. is that currently possible in android?

Comment: What do you mean by "see custom url scheme"? Do you want to register your application as being able to receive that intent?

Comment: "I want my app to call a method" -- but you said that you do not want your app to be launched, which means it may not be running and therefore cannot call a method. "and return a string" -- return to what?

Comment: possible interpretation, you want your WEB app to call into native code and have a string value returned?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, so for example within iOS what you can do is register a url scheme and bind it to a specific protocol handler and from there it can do whatever you program the method to do.

I'm looking for this same functionality in android. What I'm trying to achieve is essentially within an Encrypted HLS stream there is a Key but that key does use the standard HTTP it uses a custom url scheme so what i want the android client to do is perform some operation when it encounters that url scheme.

Comment: answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023273/android-custom-url-scheme

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android custom url scheme..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023273/android-custom-url-scheme)