# android url scheme or javascript interface?

Tags: javascript, android, json, html

I have a html 5 single url based app (written using slingshot), which has features of sending email to a specific date and time based on user requirements. I used android webview to access the app. The email functionality explained above need to be transferred to android local notification. Setting up notification is not the issue, the issue is how to get the web layer json data in my android native layer to set the local notification.

Not sure if I can use [javascript interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544671/how-to-call-javascript-from-android/7544818#7544818) as i am not going to call any method from my web app. The save button i have in my web app will trigger the json dada which i want to capture in android layer. I was thinking to user [intent filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023273/android-custom-url-scheme) to capture the url scheme but didn't really find any good example as most of the example is showing local html file coming from asset directory. But in my case i have a html 5 single url app (written using slingshot) triggering the data when save button is getting click.

didn't really find any good references stuck here , please help.

Comment: Google "shouldOverrideUrlLoading". Sorry, don't have time to give you a complete answer right now.

Comment: @323go Would you please be more specific, if you do have little time today. Thanks

Comment: When you click the save button, is there an HTTP request made that returns that JSON data?  Where does it come from?

Comment: If the JSON comes from an HTTP request, then in the callback for the request I'd recommend using a javascript interface to then pass the data to the Android layer.  If you already have the data without an HTTP request, I'd still recommend using a javascript interface to pass the data to the Android layer of your app.