# Android - URL Scheme

Tags: android, url-scheme

Just wondering why this isn't working for me:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MainDrawerActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="myapp" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

When I open my browser and type myapp://test nothing happens. Am I missing something?

Comment: try this: `<data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="test"/>`. By the way, have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023273/android-custom-url-scheme and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-scheme-on-android ?

Comment: I've seen them both and tried your example and still doesn't work. Maybe I'm testing it wrong. Can I just put that url in my browser?

Comment: yes, you can. custom urls are deprecated in fact, but it should works. what android version do you have?

Comment: 4.2.2 - if they are deprecated what is used now to do custom urls?

Comment: the right way is using the default schemes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/525086/3345366 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/1609662/3345366. But the custom schemes on android 4.2.2 works too. Maybe, you need to correct your handler?

Comment: When you say handler, what do you mean? I thought if you add that scheme in, it will automatically know to open the app.