# Android: Clicking URL not showing my application

Tags: android, json, shareactionprovider

I have developed an application in which there is one URL(JSON Link): https://zappos.amazon.com/mobileapi/v1/product/asin/B00LLS8LQU

I have shared this URL in whatsApp or any other application.
I have two Queries

My Query is: When the user clicks the URL.
 My Application should be shown along with browsers.
Query 2:
After clicking on my application provided by action provider.
I need to get data from this JSON URL Link? How i can achieve that?
Below is the screenshot of problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, learn everything [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4027138/2413972).

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/intents-filters.html)